# Creating Dynamic button at runtime in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

Hello i want to create a new button in my windows phone application without using the toolbox only code behind

it's posssible to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the object in code and add it to an appropriate container.

As a really simple example.

Create a new Windows Phone (Silverlight) project and change the code behind of MainPage.xaml.cs to be:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var myCodeGeneratedButton = new Button { Content = "press me" };

        myCodeGeneratedButton.Click +=
            (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("You pressed me",
                                              "Thank you",
                                              MessageBoxButton.OK);

        this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(myCodeGeneratedButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to create this chart with amchart

<chart>
  <series>
    <value xid="0">Not Submitted: 20</value>
    <value xid="1">Submitted: 11</value>
    <value xid="2">Rejected: 2</value>
  </series>
  <graphs>
    <graph gid="0">
      <value xid="0" color="#FF0000">20</value>
      <value xid="1" color="#00FF00">11</value>
      <value xid="2" color="#0000FF">2</value>
    </graph>
    <graph gid="1">
      <value xid="0" color="#FF0000">24</value>
      <value xid="1" color="#00FF00">7</value>
      <value xid="2" color="#0000FF">4</value>
    </graph>
  </graphs>
</chart>